# matlab text input delimeters

Tags: matlab, text, file-io

I am trying to read a text file into matlab where the text file has been designed so that the columns are right-aligned so that my columns look like,

```
    3        6      10.5
   13       12       9.5
  104        5    200000
```

This has given me two situations that I'm not sure how to handle in matlab, the first is the whitespace before the first data and the other is the variable number of whitespace characters in each row which seems to be beyond my knowledge of textscan. I'm tempted to use sed to reformat the text file but I'm sure this is trivial to someone. Is there a way that I can an arbitrary amount of whitespace as the delimeter (and have the line start with the delimeter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `load` command:

```
 l = load('C:\myFile.txt')
```

It will work as long as you have only numbers, and same number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp on every line.

```
M = regexp(str, '\w+(\d+)','tokens')
```